# How can I create code blocks in my own language after Lexing In Python?

Tags: python, nested, token, codeblocks, lexical-analysis

I'm creating a new language in Python and have run into a problem.

Let's say I have this code.

```
if (1=1){
    print('Hi')
};
```

Note: The above is the language I'm creating

So, I Lex it into:

```py
[{type:"IF" , value:"if"} , {type:"{" , value:"{"} , {type:"PRINT" , value:"print"} , {type:"(" , value:"("} , {type:"'" , value:"'"} , {type:"ID" , value:"HI"}, {type:"'" , value:"'"} , {type:";" , value:";"} {type:"}" , value:"}"} , {type:";" , value:";"}]
```

The way I transpile it into Python takes it one statement at a time into a function. I get the statement by using the ';' tokens as a full stop.

```py
size = len(lexer) #TheTokens
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in
   enumerate(lexer) if val.type == ';'] 
res = [lexer[i: j] for i, j in
   zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + 
   ([size] if idx_list[-1] != size else []))]
```

I then use a for loop to run through every statement and transpile them one by one.

Here's where the problem starts. The Loops and Conditions have codeblock and my code separates all the statements inside the code block as well. I want the whole for loop, or the whole if condition to be taken as one statement.

I got a pretty basic fix by making all the semicolons inside a code block comas, separating the statements and turning the code block commas into semicolons again. But that doesn't work for nested code blocks.

What should I do?

Comment: Compiling to python isn't an extremely great idea... Might be too slow :)

Comment: `'Hi'` is one token, not three. And `Hi` is not an identifier, or even the syntactic equivalent to an identifier. The string could just as well have been `print('&#42!'):`

Comment: The Hi token works. The Print Statement also works for all integers, strings and even expressions of integers with plus, minus, multiply and divide. That is not the problem.

Comment: I know compiling is not a good idea, but I'm new to this area and so, I'm doing this as its easier. Speed is not that big of a concern for me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a list of tokens, the next step is to parse them and build a nested version of the tokens in some form.

Parsing works according to a 'grammar' that describes how tokens combine to form bigger structures.

One way of writing down a grammar is EBNF:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

For your example above, a grammar like this might work:

```
statement = if_statement | print_statement
print_statement = PRINT ( ' ID ' ) ;
if_statement = IF ( condition ) block ;
condition = ... define if condition syntax
block = { statement_list }
statement_list = statement | statement statement_list
```

This is just a notation for the grammar, not code to parse with, but the important thing is the `statement_list` definition, that allows a `statement_list` to be a single `statement`, or a `statement` followed by another `statement_list`.

To write a parser from scratch to implement this grammar, the simplest way is to use a recursive descent parser:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser
That wiki page has an example of C code to parse a mini language.

This looks at the tokens one at a time, and based on what the next token is (or next several tokens are), it starts parsing and remembers partly constructed pieces as it goes along. So for your example program, if a valid program is made of a list of statements, we know the next token has to be 'IF' or 'PRINT'. The parser sees the 'IF' token first, and knows it must be parsing an if statement.
Then it keeps going, expecting to find brackets and a condition. Once it goes past the first '{' it knows any statement can come next, so it looks to see if the next token is a 'PRINT' or an 'IF' and parses the print statement next. Then it sees the last '}' and completes the earlier IF statement, which now knows it has the PRINT statement inside its block.

This method of parsing means that your first IF statement can contain another IF statement, which can contain yet another IF statement, with a PRINT inside that.

You can then extend the language with more statements like FOR, WHILE etc.

If the grammar gets big and complex, there are tools to build parsers directly from grammars. For python I have used one called PLY, which you can get here:
https://github.com/dabeaz/ply

This means you put chunks of python comments into special functions that describe the grammar in a form very similar to EBNF. Ply then works out what order to call the functions in automatically, and in each function you write python that does something when a complete if statement is seen, or a complete print statement etc.

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing with my language is to create the abstract syntax tree from my parsed code. I do not even bother with real lexing or anything too complicated.
For code blocks I use simple stacks to enter and exit them. I use collections.deque() for that.

You write the equivalent Python code, get the AST from them and examine the resulting tree. In this way you quickly learn how Python is interpreted. Then you know how to write Python using abstract Syntax trees. My compiler walks through my code in a tree fashion, therefore it is pretty easy to create the AST while simultaneously parsing the code.

After the AST is completed you can compile it into Python byte code and execute using exec or you can even save it as *.pyc and start it as a regular Python or import it.

This guarantees you maximal possible speed. Your language does not translate to Python but compiles to it and it goes directly to the Python Virtual Machine.
From the AST you can then write Python code if you really want, although this is a step in a decompilation, and although not difficult, it can get complicated.

So, I advise you to use a while loop with stacks for entering and exiting blocks and subblocks. How you tokenize the code is up to you. If you want you can build the AST during the traversal using the ast module, and then compile() it. If you need interpreting you exec it at the line or, in case you are in the block,  after block is closed, i.e. after block stack is empty again. Writing Python while walking your code would be easier, I admit, but you will be losing speed.

To simplify things I created my own classes to represent blocks, subblocks and conditions. E.g. a condition can have if, elif and else subblocks. A function or a loop is considered a block, and anything nested is a subblock. The objects in questions contain methods that translate them to AST chunks. One line has its own object, I call it a Command(), and comments have their class too, but they are just ignored during the AST creation. So I fill-in my objects with my code according to the code's context, inside my loop, and then ask them to parse it further and get me the AST chunk to add it to the tree. And bang. Python byte code is a result.

Ow, yes, in block classes I keep track of the line being interpreted and a token inside it. So if I detect a syntax error inside my code I can report it.